# Keeping on getting Could not load error (361) in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This is my code for listing two text boxes and to select data from one to another. Previously it was working fine. Now it keep on showing `"Could not load or unload this object"`

I tried removing `option explicit` , I deleted a module which was opening this form. Nothing is working. I a added a button click command and then it showed this error. On button click, I just tried to hide this form and show another form. But after that on wards this error is shown. I removed that lines of code and tried. Still it is not working

My code :

```
Private Sub BTN_moveAllLeft_Click()

    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.ListBox2.List(iCtr)
    Next iCtr

    Me.ListBox2.Clear
End Sub
Private Sub BTN_moveAllRight_Click()

    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCtr)
    Next iCtr

    Me.ListBox1.Clear
End Sub
Private Sub BTN_MoveSelectedLeft_Click()

    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox2.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.ListBox2.List(iCtr)
        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.ListBox2.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox2.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr

End Sub
Private Sub BTN_MoveSelectedRight_Click()

    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCtr)
        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr

End Sub

'Private Sub cancel_Click()
'Unload.Me
'End Sub

'Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
'frmListBoxTest.Hide
' UserForm2.Show
'End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim iCtr As Long

    With Me.ListBox1

            .AddItem "1"
            .AddItem "B"
            .AddItem "D"
            .AddItem "G"
            .AddItem "A"
            .AddItem "BS"
            .AddItem "MR"
            .AddItem "Ig"
            .AddItem "Eng"
            .AddItem "BE"
            .AddItem "CS"
            .AddItem "PS"
            .AddItem "C"
            .AddItem "TN"
            .AddItem "HC"
            .AddItem "Cy"
            .AddItem "P"
            .AddItem "Dr"
            .AddItem "ER"


    End With



    Me.ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
    Me.ListBox2.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti

End Sub
```

Previously there was a module named `module 1` which had the code to show this userform.

And `Option Explicit` was also there in this form code. I removed that.

Images of errors :

[image]
[image]

Comment: NEVER remove `Option Explicit` - it can never be the source of an error and will prevent you from making "stupid" mistakes (typos). Which line of code or which actions are triggering which errors? If you removed the module that shows the form what are you doing to show the form, now? Is there any other code in the UserForm code module than what you show us? Where's the button click command you added?

Comment: button click i made as commnt

Comment: I think you need to use Unload Me without the dot.

Comment: but even if  i commented it..its showing error

Comment: In what line does it show the error? Can you go through the code by adding a break and pressing F8 until you come to the line where the error shows up?

Answer (score 0):

It used to work, now it doesn't. Most likely reason, if you haven't changed anything, is that the compiled code is corrupt.

```
Step 1: export all modules and forms from the vb editor. 
Step 2: save the file as an xlsx (thus removing all vb code)
step 3: Open the xlsx and import all the modules and forms
Step 4: recompile the code (debug,compile)
step 5: save as xlsm
```